# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ to be irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, alternative-proof

This is not for homework, and I am not totally convinced I understand the question entirely.  Also, I'm not allowed to use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD.  The question asks

> Show that $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible if and only if $f(x)$ is either a prime integer or an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that the $\gcd$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ of the coefficients of $f(x)$ is $1$.

The part of the question I am finding confusing is the phrasing "...or an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that the $\gcd$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ of the coefficients...".  What is the $\gcd$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ of the coefficients of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?  Does the author mean to multiply $f(x)$ by an integer $c$ such that the coefficients of $cf(x)$ are integers, and then look at the $\gcd$ of *those* coefficients?  Under this tentative assumption of what the question is asking, here is what I have so far.

If $f(x)$ is a prime integer or an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that the $\gcd$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ of the coefficients of $f(x)$ is $1$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (this follows from a theorem that states: "a polynomial $f(x)$ factors as a product of polynomials of degree $m$ and $n$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ if and only if $f(x)$ factors as a product of polynomials of degree $m$ and $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$").

Conversely, suppose $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  If $\deg (f(x)) = 0$, then it is not hard to see that $f(x)$ must be a prime integer.  If $\deg (f(x)) > 0$, then I can again use the result quoted in the last paragraph to say that $f(x)$ cannot be written as the product of polynomials of lower degree in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ (for if it could, then $f(x)$ would be reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$).  At this point, I'm not sure how to show that the $\gcd$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ of the coefficients of $f(x)$ is $1$.  I'm also a bit uneasy about the approach in general.  Critiques and hints are very welcome!

Comment: $f$ is assumed to be in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the condition in the question states that $f$ is irreducible as a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but $f$ still has integer coefficients and so the gcd makes sense.

Comment: The author views $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. (Since $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Q}$.) So the alternative is 1. a constant polynomial whose constant term is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$, or 2. a polynomial (with integer coefficients) that is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, and whose coefficients are coprime.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I have the attention span of a gnat apparently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks about *irreducibility* in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but the polynomial itself is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  So there is always a g.c.d., without anything special happening.

As for your last question: how about a proof by contradiction?  What would happen if the g.c.d. of the coefficients were *not* $1$?

Comment: I see.  If the $\gcd$ of the coefficients is not $1$ then we can pull out a prime factor, contradicting the irreducibility of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  Adding this into the sketch I posted above, can you see anything else glaringly wrong?

Comment: @tylerc0816 Nope, it's all correct, and shows pretty good form.  One minor quibble I have is in the first paragraph, where you say "this follows from a theorem that states..."  I'd be slightly more specific about how it follows, because it's not clear where you're using the gcd.  I know you said it's not for homework, but I'm of the philosophy that we learn to write proofs because we eventually want to communicate ideas to other humans, and humans are notorious for getting confused easily.  But otherwise, looks solid, and good job.

Comment: Thank you.  In fact I believe the assumption about the $\gcd$ is irrelevant when quoting that theorem.  More specifically, I could have said "since $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, it cannot be written as the product of two polynomials of lower degree, and hence cannot be written as the product of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of lower degree", not bringing up the assumption about the $\gcd$ at all.  I believe the assumption about the $\gcd$ is needed only for proving the other direction.

Comment: @tylerc0816 Not so.  If you are trying to prove that $2x+3$ is irreducible, and you don't use the fact that its coefficients are relatively prime, then you have made a mistake.  $2x+4$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ but not $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  Oh, and this is the reason I forgot to mention for writing more detailed proofs; you see your own mistakes easier :)